# Powershell Script invoking async method?

Tags: powershell

I need to invoke an async method of a CLR type like this:

```
$tokenTask = $tokenProvider.AcquireAccessToken()
$tokenTask.Wait()
Write-Output "Token: $($tokenTask.Result)"
```

This in not working since it for some reason cannot successfully invoke `Wait`:

```
Exception calling "Wait" with "0" argument(s): "One or more errors occurred."
At D:\UserManagement\STP.UserManagement.Identity.Client\STP.UserManagement.Identity.Client.Sample\authenticate.ps1:8 char:1
+ $tokenTask.Wait()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AggregateException
```

How can I wait and get the result of my async method?
Is there a keyword like `await` in PowerShell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was that my task was `Faulted` right from the start because of missing Add-Type for another assembly. I found it like this:

```
$tokenTask = $tokenProvider.AcquireAccessToken()
Write-Output "authenticating... ($($tokenTask.Status), $($tokenTask.Exception))"
$tokenTask.Wait()
Write-Output "authenticated ($($tokenTask.Status), $($tokenTask.Exception))"
```